# Работа с треем программы

Tags: c#, wpf

Сворачиваю программу в трей при нажатии клавиш таким образом:

```
this.notifyIcon = new System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon();
this.notifyIcon.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon("logo3.ico");
this.notifyIcon.Visible = true;  
this.Hide();
```

Программа сворачивается, но как сделать обработку событий при нажатии правой или левой кнопки?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам следует подписаться на события `System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon`.
Например, так:

```
notifyIcon.MouseClick += (o, e) => MessageBox.Show("Clicked!");
```